# AWS RedShift: Concurrency scaling not adding clusters during spike

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-redshift

WE have set up Redshift and are trying to implement WorkLoadManagement. We have set out Concurrency Scaling mode to **auto** using manual and auto WLM.

[image: concurrency scaling]

Upon adding load onto the Redshift Cluster, the **CPU Utilization** hits the 100% mark but upon checking the workload concurrency no additional clusters have been added.

[image: cpu]
[image: workload concurrency]

Below are my WLM parameters that I have set

[image: wlm parameters]

What could I be missing in my configuration that doe not allow an additional cluster to be added during a spike?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concurrency Scaling clusters are added when a WLM slots are taken by running queries and other queries are waiting for a WLM slot to execute.

It does **not** add clusters in response to high CPU since Redshift is designed to use as much CPU as possible (for maximum speed!).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/concurrency-scaling.html

Comment: Hi yes, thank you for your answer, we were running creat table queries thus concurrency scaling was not working